# Speeding up a PHP App

Tags: php, mysql, performance, multithreading

I have a list of data that needs to be processed. The way it works right now is this:

- A user clicks a process button.
- The PHP code takes the first item that needs to be processed, takes 15-25 secs to process it, moves on to the next item, and so on.

This takes way too long. What I'd like instead is that:

- The user clicks the process button.
- A PHP script takes the first item and starts to process it.
- Simultaneously another instance of the script takes the next item and processes it.
- And so on, so around 5-6 of the items are being process simultaneously and we get 6 items processed in 15-25 secs instead of just one.

Is something like this possible?

I was thinking that I use CRON to launch an instance of the script every second. All items that need to be processed will be flagged as such in the MySQL database, so whenever an instance is launched through CRON, it will simply take the next item flagged to be processed and remove the flag.

Thoughts?

Edit: To clarify something, each 'item' is stored in a mysql database table as seperate rows. Whenever processing starts on an item, it is flagged as being processed in the db, hence each new instance will simply grab the next row which is not being processed and process it. Hence I don't have to supply the items as command line arguments.

Comment: How many items are you processing, and what on EARTH are you processing ?

Comment: what OS is/are your server[s] running on? (*hopes they're all linux or unix*)

Comment: Why is it taking 15-25 seconds per item? If it is because the CPU is maxed out, any sort of multi-threading solution will make it take longer. If it is because disk IO or network bandwidth is the bottleneck, multi-threading will not make it any faster.

Have you profiled the application and do you know what the current bottleneck is so you can avoid taking a slow application and turning it into a more complicated and harder to maintain slow application?

Comment: You cannot launch CRON items every second. And even if you could, no hosting provider would let you. See http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/seting-cron-to-run-a-script-every-second-425623/

Comment: Please answer mattjames' questions, as they will shed a lot of light on the system. Have you profiled your code to find out where the bottlenecks are? All the solutions below add a lot of complication and extra code (and extra bugs) so I'd invest more time profiling and optimizing the single threaded case first.

Comment: @mattjames and @sam, I've done some profiling and half of the 15-25 secs are spent doing a request to a google API and getting their response. The rest is just spent in the processing, there's a lot that has to be done, each item has dozens of further sub-items that need to be processed.

Comment: Can you do the Google API request as a socket connection?  Do these items HAVE to go in order?  If you answered Yes and No, it's possible to send multiple socket requests at once, so you could be waiting about 20secs for like 50 requests, in fact I have a PHP app that does this.

Comment: @TravisO, my answers are I don't know, and no. The items don't have to go in order, however what do you mean by the google requests done as 'socket connections', can you explain? Also, the processing will have to wait until the info from google is returned. Feel free to submit your reply as a new answer

Comment: @TravisO, if you want to answer about the sockets you can do so on my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107536/how-to-open-multiple-socket-connections-and-do-callbacks-in-php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one solution, not the greatest, but will work fine on Linux:

Split the processing PHP into a separate CLI scripts in which:

- The command line inputs include `$id` and `$item`

  The script writes its PID to a file in `/tmp/$id.$item.pid`

  The script echos results as XML or something that can be read into PHP to stdout

  When finished the script deletes the `/tmp/$id.$item.pid` file

Your master script (presumably on your webserver) would do:

- `exec("nohup php myprocessing.php $id $item > /tmp/$id.$item.xml");` for each item

  Poll the `/tmp/$id.$item.pid` files until all are deleted (sleep/check poll is enough)

  If they are never deleted kill all the processing scripts and report failure

  If successful read the from `/tmp/$id.$item.xml` for format/output to user

  Delete the XML files if you don't want to cache for later use

A backgrounded `nohup` started application will run independent of the script that started it.

This interested me sufficiently that I decided to write a POC.

test.php

```
<?php
$dir =  realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
$start = time();

// Time in seconds after which we give up and kill everything
$timeout = 25;

// The unique identifier for the request
$id = uniqid();

// Our "items" which would be supplied by the user
$items = array("foo", "bar", "0xdeadbeef");

// We exec a nohup command that is backgrounded which returns immediately
foreach ($items as $item) {
    exec("nohup php proc.php $id $item > $dir/proc.$id.$item.out &");
}

echo "<pre>";
// Run until timeout or all processing has finished
while(time() - $start < $timeout) 
{
  echo (time() - $start), " seconds\n";
  clearstatcache();    // Required since PHP will cache for file_exists
  $running = array();
  foreach($items as $item)
  {
      // If the pid file still exists the process is still running    
      if (file_exists("$dir/proc.$id.$item.pid")) {
          $running[] = $item;
      }
  }
  if (empty($running)) break;
  echo implode($running, ','), " running\n";
  flush();
  sleep(1);  
}

// Clean up if we timeout out
if (!empty($running)) {
    clearstatcache();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // Kill process of anything still running (i.e. that has a pid file)
        if(file_exists("$dir/proc.$id.$item.pid") 
            && $pid = file_get_contents("$dir/proc.$id.$item.pid")) {
            posix_kill($pid, 9);                
            unlink("$dir/proc.$id.$item.pid");
            // Would want to log this in the real world
            echo "Failed to process: ", $item, " pid ", $pid, "\n";
    }
    // delete the useless data
    unlink("$dir/proc.$id.$item.out");
    }
} else {
    echo "Successfully processed all items in ", time() - $start, " seconds.\n";
    foreach ($items as $item) {
    // Grab the processed data and delete the file
        echo(file_get_contents("$dir/proc.$id.$item.out"));
        unlink("$dir/proc.$id.$item.out");
    }
}
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

proc.php

```
<?php
$dir =  realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
$id = $argv[1];
$item = $argv[2];

// Write out our pid file
file_put_contents("$dir/proc.$id.$item.pid", posix_getpid());

for($i=0;$i<80;++$i)
{
    echo $item,':', $i, "\n";
    usleep(250000);
}

// Remove our pid file to say we're done processing
unlink("proc.$id.$item.pid");

?>
```

Put test.php and proc.php in the same folder of your server, load test.php and enjoy.

You will of course need nohup (unix) and PHP cli to get this to work.

Lots of fun, I may find a use for it later.

Comment: A nice solution, my only concern is the nohup, how can I check if my server has this installed? I don't need to pass the arguments via command line, they're stored in the db so the `proc.php` file will just fetch the next pending item from the db and process it, no arguments need to be passed on. Assuming that's what the php cli is needed for i wont need it.

Comment: `nohup` is part of the coreutils package which includes such things as `ls`, `cd`, etc.  I'd be surprised if any Linux server doesn't have it. All `nohup` does is: "run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty". Since exec effectively runs things as though you were using a shell you need the PHP binary to be available to run your PHP scripts. If it isn't then there's a way around it as if `wget` is installed you can do the same trick but pull webpages from your server (you really don't want to do it that way if possible).

Answer (score 5):

Use an external workqueue like [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/) which your PHP script writes a bunch of jobs too. You have as many worker processes pulling jobs from beanstalkd and processing them as fast as possible. You can spin up as many workers as you have memory / CPU. Your job body should contain as little information as possible, maybe just some IDs which you hit the DB with. beanstalkd has a slew of client APIs and itself has a very basic API, think memcached.

We use beanstalkd to process all of our background jobs, I love it. Easy to use, its very fast.

Comment: Gearman is also a good solution for external work outsourcing.

Comment: You can also do this with redis nowadays because it has a blocking pop function. See http://simonwillison.net/2010/Jan/7/blocking/

Comment: Can this be used automatically/programatically? I'm not looking for anything done through the command line, and looking to do as little sysadmin work as possible. The installation also looks hard?

Answer (score 1):

There is no multithreading in PHP, however you can use fork.

[php.net:pcntl-fork](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php)

Or you could execute a system() command and start another process which is multithreaded.

Comment: can you give some sample code or more detail on the system() function?

Answer (score 1):

can you implementing threading in javascript on the client side? seems to me i've seen a javascript library (from google perhaps?) that implements it. google it and i'm sure you'll find something. i've never done it, but i know its possible. anyway, your client-side javascript could activate (ajax) a php script once for each item in separate threads. that might be easier than trying to do it all on the server side.

-don

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a high traffic PHP server you are **INSANE**  if you do not use Alternative PHP Cache: http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php  . You do not have to make code modifications to run APC.

Another useful technique that can work along with APC is using the Smarty template system which allows you to cache output so that pages do not have to be rebuilt.

Comment: Nothing @ all to do with the question asked

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I've used two different products; Gearman and RabbitMQ.

The benefit of putting your jobs into some sort of queuing software like Gearman or Rabbit is that you have multiple machines, they can all participate in processing items off the queue(s).

Gearman is easier to setup, so I'd suggest poking around with it a bit first.  If you find you need something more heavy duty with queue robustness; Look into RabbitMQ

- http://www.danga.com/gearman/
- http://pear.php.net/package/Net_Gearman (PEAR library)

Answer (score -1):

You can use pcntl_fork() and family to fork a process - however you may need something like IPC to communicate back to the parent process that the child process (the one you fork'd) is finished.

You could have them write to shared memory, like via memcache or a DB.

You could also have the child process write the completed data to a file, that the parent process keeps checking - as each child process completes the file is created/written to/updated, and parent process can grab it, one at a time, and them throw them back to the callee/client.

The parent's job is to control the queue, to make sure the same data isn't processed twice and also to sanity check the children (better kill that runaway process and start over...etc)

Something else to keep in mind - on windows platforms you are going to be severely limited - I dont even think you have access to pcntl_ unless you compiled PHP with support for it.

Also, can you cache the data once its been processed, or is it unique data every time? that would surely speed things up..?

Comment: Well, you don't really need IPC to tell when a child process is done. You can spawn several child processes, giving each one a file to put its result in, then use `pcntl-wait` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-wait.php) to wait for the child processes to complete. When each one completes, pull in its data, and `pcntl-wait` again for the next one, keeping track until all children have returned.

Comment: Yeah that's true - I gave a few examples of not using IPC ( in fact I also gave an example of using a file) but really, we're all still talking about shared memory.

Comment: I want to say yes, but should check php.net - I think for windows we ended up using: http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php Ugh, COM!

Comment: I don't need to communicate back and forth. I just need a way of launching another instance of a php script. It will just take the next item flagged as needing to be processed from the db and process it. Any thoughts on how that'll be done?